# MS Dynamics CRM, Web resources (.html) and "custom" Doctype

Tags: html, dynamics-crm, doctype, dynamics-crm-2011, webresource

I'm trying to create heat map on bing maps ajax control using some data from CRM database. For that I created web resource and uploaded it to CRM. I set up button which when clicked open my web resource (.html) with heat maps. Because I'm using BingMaps Ajax v7 control and HTML5 canvas for displaying generated heatmap (as image) I need to have Doctype declaration on my web resource. But everytime when I put that in my html page, while uploading it to CRM (or editing), CRM just delete my Doctype and then I only have

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
</body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Heat map is working great because I tested it on my local machine (outside CRM). Using IE Dev tools I'm getting error that getContext() method is not found... So, my guess is that I'm missing doctype which CRM deletes every time when I edit or upload web resource. So my question is how to successfully show HTML5 content in Microsoft Dynamics CRM using Web resource (plain .HTML file). I don't need to have that web resource in CRM form page... When I click map button, web resources need to be opened in separate browser page.....

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLUTION

If you ever hit this like me, don't use CRM TextEditor because he is removing Doctype tag when you edit your resource using him..

Solution is to edit your web resource on your local machine using your personal text editor and upload it again in CRM. And in this case Doctype tag will be there..